# rake db:create Can't initialize character set utf8mb4

Tags: mysql

My sinatra app running under CentOS 6.5 server. When i run `"rake db:create RACK_ENV=production"`, i got the error:

```
Character set 'utf8mb4' is not a compiled character set 
and is not specified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file
```

My database configration:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[:production] = {
  :adapter   => 'mysql2',
  :encoding  => 'utf8mb4',
  ...
```

I have changed mysql my.conf, still got the error.

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Here is in mysql shell:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_general_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Mysql version:

```
Server version: 5.6.23 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Any help? thanks!

Comment: Do you use MySQL 5.5+ ? It seems utf8mb4 is not supported before that.

Comment: Any solution please ?

Comment: @BackPacker it's long time i forgot but checkout mysql version, seems i installed two versions of mysql, be sure you configure the right one or update to the latest version and check it out. Hope give u some hint.